# Screen freeze when navigate in react native navigation with Drawer navigation

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation

I have an issue with Drawer navigation in React Native Navigation.

The problem seems to be very simple.

I have 2 screens, on each screen I have a button that sends the user to the other one.

the **problem** is after sending the user from screen A to B and from B to A the button does not work anymore.

I can pull the drawer and go back to the B screen again, and the Button works there, but the button in the A screen is still frozen, the hole screen basically.

```js
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import SettingScreen from "../screens/SettingScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "../screens/ProfileScreen";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MenuNavigation(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Setting" component={SettingScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default MenuNavigation;
```

this is one of the screens the other one is the same with exception of names

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

function SettingScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile Screen"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Profile")}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default SettingScreen;
```

similar to Setting Screen I have a Profile Screen, which I didn't include.

```js
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import MenuNavigation from "./MenuNavigation";

function MainNavigation(props) {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MenuNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainNavigation;
```

and finally, this is my package.json file and yes I'm using EXPO

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~1.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.14.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-modals": "^0.22.3",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-connect": "^10.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

no Error no nothing, simply does not work.

If anyone needs more detail just ask me.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I see that there's a commit related to this though I am not 100% sure of that. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/60fe0dbb0ae443fdb21016d368c919b933cb64e7.

Comment: Oh wow i was just about to ask this thanks OP !

Comment: This needs to be a github issue

Comment: @AniruddhaPandey Yes, I do believe this must be fixed. Because one of the examples in official documentation does not work correctly anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the newest version `5.12.2` of `@react-navigation/drawer` has this issue. So I tried with an older version `5.11.5` and it worked for me.
I tested on an adroid mobile only though.
 
Command to install a specific npm packager version is:
   `yarn add @react-navigation/drawer@5.11.5`

Answer (score 2):

React-Navigation/drawer version 5.12.3 addresses this issue:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/releases/tag/%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%405.12.3

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into the same problem today. I don't know if you've found the solution already but I've been messing around with the library and found a random quick fix. I don't even understand how it works though and I'm new to React.
May be you could try Looking further into this.

So I change the opacity of ResourceSavingScene component in react-navigation/drawer/src/DrawerView.tsx to always 1.

```
<ResourceSavingScene
 key={route.key}
 /*style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { opacity: isFocused ? 1 : 0 }]}*/
 style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFill, { opacity: 1 }]}
 isVisible={isFocused}
 enabled={detachInactiveScreens}
>
```

It seems to work (I've tested using android emulator) but as I said I still don't understand it. Inpecting the element in android emulator got me confused how this component styling behave.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well but is there not a permanent solution for this problem ?

Comment: Looks like the package has been updated and the issue has been fixed by the author. Version 5.12.3 should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so i tried to downgrade to drawer@5.11.5 but nothing changed.

I don't know why but MAN.TOGA Solution worked fine.